# puppeteer hangs chromium on request.continue if header is modified on 302 response code

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

Chromium is getting hanged if header is modified using puppeteer

- Puppeteer version:1.12.2
- Platform / OS version: MAC / UBUNTU

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  try {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on('request', request => {
      const headers = Object.assign({}, request.headers(), {
         foo: 'bar'
      });
      request.continue({ headers });
    });

    await page.goto('http://google.com');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: As per https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3973, `await page.goto('http://google.com');` should be an URL with a redirect to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt thanks, i edited the bug report but no one is there to fix this bug? do you have any clue to fix it?

Comment: No, sorry. Unfortunately, puppeteer currently has a very limited community of contributors, and most of them have time only to add some new features (they increase firefox support now, for example). So some issues can only wait longer to be fixed.

Comment: And sorry for confusing: I meant you need to replace `await page.goto('http://google.com');` with `await page.goto('https://is.gd...');` here to reproduce the issue, as in the initial report)

Comment: I tried to post as it is but StackOverflow restrict URL shortener

Comment: even I'm facing this annoying issue.. would like to hear any solutoin about it

Comment: @khizaransari Let's try `await page.goto('https://is.gd/' + 'OwycZW');`

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt http://google.com redirect to http://www.google.com/ that why I added this

Comment: But I cannot reproduce the issue with google.com. Can you?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt foo: bar was uncommented in above code, i edit it. yes i'm able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've missed that. Now I also can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was not relevant to setting headers.

When I enabled request interception with this line of code observing the same behavior:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
```

If I comment out this line of code it is loading the page but the Chromium is complaining that the connection is insecure. In this case waitUntil option does not work within page.goto as option.

If I open a new tab in Chromium (the same window) and copy and paste the same url it is loading the page without any isues.